# PHP mySQL result array - while a row's id remains the same do something, when the row's id changes move on

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which is searching a database for orders. My SQL query returns order information with the order id being the key (the id is repeating for orders with more than one product) and order information attached to that including product qty and variation.

The query joins a few tables and outputs as follows

```
|--orderid--|--orderstatus--|--ordcustid--|--orderprodname--|--orderprodqty--|--orderqty--|
|---12635---|-----11--------|-----4192----|----Product1-----|--------1-------|-----2------|
|---12635---|-----11--------|-----4192----|----Product2-----|--------1-------|-----2------|
|---12636---|-----11--------|-----3531----|----Product3-----|--------1-------|-----1------|
```

As you can see above. Customer 4192 has made 1 order (orderid 12635) that has 2 products. Customer 3531 has made 1 order that has 1 product (orderid 12636).

I'm wanting to capture the information for each order and put it together. So while the order id is the same I'm collecting the information.

My current script looks like this, but it just works on every row.

```
$result = mysql_query(" 
    SELECT * 
    FROM  orders, orderproducts, productimage, customers
    WHERE orders.orderid = orderproducts.orderorderid
    AND orderproducts.orderprodid = productimage.imageprodid
    AND orders.ordcustid = customers.customerid
    AND ordstatus = '11'
    ORDER BY orderid
");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
//do stuff
}
```

The purpose of the script is to mail the information for each order. What my current script is doing is mailing the customer for every product (i.e. customer 4192 would get two separate emails - 1 for Product1 and 1 for Product2). What I'm wanting to do is email customer 4192 with both products on the same email.

How can I improve my script so that while the orderid is the same it will get information from all of the rows where the orderid is the same (eg orderproductname, qty ) and then continue when the order id changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this bit of code before your loop:

```
 $last_id = 0;
```

And in your while() loop:

```
 if ( $last_id != $row['orderid'] ) {
      // New Order - do some initiation stuff
      $last_id = $row['orderid'];
 } else {
      // Continuing the current order - do some different stuff
 }
```

Here's the code altogether:

```
$result = mysql_query(" 
    SELECT * 
    FROM  orders, orderproducts, productimage, customers
    WHERE orders.orderid = orderproducts.orderorderid
    AND orderproducts.orderprodid = productimage.imageprodid
    AND orders.ordcustid = customers.customerid
    AND ordstatus = '11'
    ORDER BY orderid
");

$last_id = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ( $last_id != $row['orderid'] ){
        // Initiate a new order

        $message_body = ''; // Reset message body for each order
        $last_id = $row['orderid']; // Keep track of the orderid last used
        if ( $last_id > 0 ){
            // Make certain we didn't just begin the loop, then email the customer

            echo "SAMPLE MESSAGE BODY FOR ORDER $last_id <br/>\r\n";
            echo $message_body;

            // Uncomment following lines to send an email
            // $headers = $headers = 'From: My Store <info@mystore.com>\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            // $success = mail( 'customer@email.com', 'Order Confirmation', $message_body, $headers);

        }
    } else {
        // Step through current order

        // Add a line to the message body for each product record
        $message_body .= "Product {$row['orderprodname']}, Qty: {$row['orderprodqty']} <br/>\r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more in the initiation stuff? I'm just a php beginner and haven't got much experience with arrays.

Comment: Sure! The initiation code could be anything -- perhaps a query to retrieve the customer's name and email, perhaps reset some data variables. You may not need to do anything besides set the `$last_id` variable. The code here is executed each time the order changes, so this is where you will want to process your order emails. I'll update my sample code to give you a more thorough example.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of which orderID you're on, and build up an email until the orderID changes. When it does, you send the email, and start a new one for the new order. e.g.

```
$cur_order = null;
$order_data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if ($cur_order !== $row['orderid']) {
      sendOrderEmail($order_data);
      $cur_order = $row['orderid'];
      $order_data = array();
   }
   $order_data[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: To test this method I've tried this however they are still coming out on separate lines:

`$cur_order= null;
$order_data= array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 if ($cur_order !== $row['orderid']) {
  $to = $row['customeremail'];
  $products = $row['orderprodname'];
  echo $to . " Your Products: " . $products . "<br/><br/><br/>";
   }
 $order_data[] = $row;
  
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option would be is to use `group_concat of product names` in the query itself. For example ,

```
SELECT *,group_concat(orderprodname) 
    FROM  orders, orderproducts, productimage, customers
    WHERE orders.orderid = orderproducts.orderorderid
    AND orderproducts.orderprodid = productimage.imageprodid
    AND orders.ordcustid = customers.customerid
    AND ordstatus = '11' group by orderid
    ORDER BY orderid
```

so you can get the product names comma separated, in a column for a particular order

Comment: This is returning #1064 sql errors... #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group_concat(orderprodname) WHERE orders.orderid = orderproducts.orderorderi' at line 2

Comment: I played around with it and this works, however I'm not sure if it will get me to my end result.

 SELECT orderid, GROUP_CONCAT( orderproducts.orderprodname )  
 FROM orders, orderproducts, productimage, customers
 WHERE orders.orderid = orderproducts.orderorderid
 AND orderproducts.orderprodid = productimage.imageprodid
 AND orders.ordcustid = customers.customerid
 AND ordstatus =  '11'
 GROUP BY orderid
 ORDER BY orderid

Comment: @James : Yes I changed the query.I hope you can get all the necessary info from this query itself.